# How can i add a property to a string to return two values, string itself and one another string(set and get)

Tags: ios, swift

How can i add a property to a string to return two values, string itself and one another string(set and get)?
Or
dose String has some property returns a string that i can set a new value?

What i want to achieve is like below:

```
var myString = "123"
func addFunc(s: String) -> String {
    myString.property = "resultString"
    return myString.property
}

let result = myString.addFunc(s: myString)
```

Comment: I I get you right: you want to use the build-in `String` type and extend it by additional stored properties?

Answer (score 1):

First, to make it clear: It is *not* possible to extend a struct or class with additional stored properties.

For classes, you could work-around this issue by using objective c runtime features, like associated objects. You'll find a lot if you search for `objc_setAssociatedObject` and/or `objc_getAssociatedObject`

For structs (and in your case, `String` is a struct), this is not supported, because they are being moved and copied around all the time, so they will sooner or later lose the relationship to their associated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a structure to do what you want.

```
struct MyString {

  var myString: String
  var property: String

}
```

You can create a getter and a setter as you wish.

EDIT:

It's possible to make an extension for what you want, BUT I strongly advise against doing it. It's not a good thing to change the implementation of String in your case.

It's better to have a struct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're planning, but you could try an extension variable with a `Tuple` type. Like so:

```
extension String {
    var myProperty2: (String, String) {
        get {
            return (self, "something you want")
        } set { }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var hello = "Hello!"
hello.myProperty2 = (hello, "Hi!")
print(hello.myProperty2)
```